# Performing an asort on a collection of objects

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object, asort

Wondering if anybody can help shed any light on what PHP is doing under the hood when performing an `asort` on a collection of objects.

Take the following snippet:

```
class NameValuePair
{
    private $name;
    private $value;

    public function __construct($name, $value)
    {
         $this->name = $name;
         $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function getName() { return $this->name; }
    public function getValue() { return $this->value; }
}

$nameValuePairs = [
    new NameValuePair('f', 'f'),
    new NameValuePair('b', 'b'),
    new NameValuePair('z', 'z'),
    new NameValuePair('s', 's')
];

asort($nameValuePairs);
```

The asort is correctly sorting the array by the `$name` property of the `NameValuePair` instances - the resulting array contains objects in the order of `bfsz`

I have implemented two unit tests - I did not expect the `asort` to correctly sort the collection and I would always use a `usort` to sort an array of objects.

Please see this gist for full context and unit tests: https://gist.github.com/mgldev/91386cc6e3d65fc239de60dc1bc46114

**General musings**

- Can't find any documentation online about how PHP treats objects within in an array when performing an asort
- Would have thought the default behaviour would be something along the lines of spl_object_hash and a sort on the hashes
- Appears to sort using the $name property of the NameValuePair instance, not the $value
- Is PHP doing something like get_object_vars() to get the object as an array and then sorting on that? get_object_vars would return an empty array on private properties though
- How is PHP getting to the $name attribute? Why is it picking the $name attribute?
- Is something else at play here?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please consider adding the minimal code necessary to reproduce the result which is causing your confusion. Externally hosted links are generally frowned up because they can become non-existent for future readers.

Comment: I thought the unit tests and test data are key to explaining this problem - without them I just have a call to `asort` with an array of objects with very little context? I do see the dead link argument though - I'll update the post with a minimal snippet and some context.

Comment: You seem to have a very well thought out question about a PHP intricacy but an entire unit test is probably overkill and has the potential to make readers dis-interested. You can certainly include the full unit test as a link somewhere but definitely try to give an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A comment to start with: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.object-comparison.php#98725

Comment: @u_mulder I was just about to mention that this seems like undocumented behavior. As such, it probably shouldn't be relied upon and can be subject to change without notice.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I suppose it is, that's why it is a comment. But it can be an explanation what is going on under the hood.

Comment: @u_mulder I do not refute that it's a good explanation and it's probably answer-worthy if you're able to expand on it a little bit. I think that if you can show an equivalent `usort()` implementation of `asort()` then that would be quite useful. I'm personally still trying to make heads or tails of the situation.

Comment: Going further it is a dupe)